# AzureDevops: Current/Future Iterations

Tags: azure-devops

Why is my iteration with start/end date in the past shown as "Future"?

As seen Iteration 1.3.3 went from Mar13 - Mar14 and today is Mar16. Why is it shown as future iteration?

[image]

These are the complete dates for the iterations shown

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You see that because 1.4.0 started earlier and Azure DevOps does not support parallel iterations in one team. The same feature request is still under review: [Allow multiple "Current" iterations for multiple iteration paths in a project](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-multiple-current-iterations-for-multiple-ite/365438)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Understood. But still I don't understand why 1.3.3 is not marked as "past". It ended two days ago (even though it started after the iteration marked as "current")